# Blender 3.0 GPU API and BGR colors

Tags: python, color, gpu-module

I want to use the new GPU API for Blender 3.0 to copy the content of a texture into a gpu.types.Buffer. Although this works fine with the following small code, I wonder how I can tell the API to copy pixel data in BGR(A) instead of RGB(A) mode. (i.e., the buffer should contain the data in reversed byte order).

```
buffer = gpu.types.Buffer('UBYTE')
framebuffer = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()
framebuffer.read_color(0, 0, 4096, 4096, 3, 0, 'UBYTE', data=buffer)
```

With the BGL API, I was able to pass the `bgl.GL_BGR(A)` parameter to the corresponding functions (e.g., `glGetTexImage`), but with the new API I don't know how to achieve the same thing. Is there a way?